# 画像を入れるか入れないかでサイトの幅が変わる

Tags: html, css

[ConciseというCSSフレームワーク](http://concisecss.com)の[Starter](http://concisecss.com/examples/starter/)というテンプレートを使用しているのですが、画像`<img src="http://...">`を`<main class="siteContent container>`の中に埋め込んだページとそうでないページで、サイトの幅が違くなってしまいます。どうすればサイトの幅を統一できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

すこし状況がよくわかりませんでしたが

```
<img width="100%">
```

上記のように画像の横幅を指定して、画像の幅がサイトの幅を超えないように指定してあげればよいのではないでしょうか。